# data driven subscription SSRS reports to share folder

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, report, subscription

I want to export reports after running, to a shared folder, but for each running create a separate folder - the running is weekly, and I want to add date to the folder name.
Is there any way that automatic every week a new folder will be created and the reports will enter there?
someone tell me to do it with data driven subscription, but i dont succedded- i dont know what to write in the query window, and after the running i get an error:
Cannot read the next data row for the data set .

someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that when you create a subsription to a report, SSRS creates a SQL Agent job on the backend.  what you should be able to do, assuming that you have access to the Reporting Server, is to modify/copy the SQL Agent Job to what you need it to do.

Failing that you could also create an SSIS package that does the same thing.